# Error in my githubacitons yml file "inputs " is not valid event name

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

Error in my githubacitons yml file "inputs " is not valid event name
name: Random
description: "Random checkout the Repository "

```
 on:
  workflow_dispatch:


 inputs:
   repo_name:
    default: ${{github.event.repository.name}}
    required: false
   PAT:
    description: 
    default: ${{github.token}}
    required: false

 runs:
  using: "composite"


jobs:
 check_out:
 steps:
    - name: "Checkout github repo"
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with: 
       repository: ${{inputs.repo_name}}
       token: ${{inputs.PAT}} 
       path: |
           basename ${{inputs.repo_name}} | tr -d ".git"
```

Error

```
   Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/checkout.yml#L1
    `inputs` is not a valid event name
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - padding matters in YML:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      repo_name:
      default: "Reponame"
      required: false
    PAT:
      description: 
      default: "TOKEN"
      required: false
```

Second thing is that you cannot use ${{ }} variables in YML definitions.

For defaults I would recommend using this instead - you can set it as ENV variable for example or use it directly as a parameter - depending on what you need to achieve:

```
${{ github.event.inputs.PAT || github.token }}
```